# How to prevent an html-template sub-folder from being refreshed during build?

Tags: apache-flex, build, refresh

I placed my AMFPHP folder inside my htmltemplate project folder, but now everytime i build it wants to 'refresh' the folder which takes forever.   Is there a way to set it so that folder does not refresh each time?   I put the AMFPHP folder in there so I can have a unique copy for my debug builds and leave the production build one alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'refresh'

The HTML-Template folder is just a template. During build all files/folders in the template folder are copied to the bin-debug (or bin-release) folder.  Is this 'copy' the refresh your talking about?

If you don't want these files copied over every time; just put them in your bin-debug / bin-release folders directly instead of the template folder.

If your AMFPHP folder contains config files; and nothing else, then you probably don't need those files in the html-template, bin-debug, or bin-release folders.  You can compile them into the SWF using the services compiler argument.

There is also a setting in the Flash Builder Project Properties that may help.  Under Flex Compiler, uncheck 'copy non-embedded files to output folder'.  However, I think this relates to files int he source directory; not the HTML Template directory.

Does any of this help?

Comment: I think I like the option of unchecking 'copy non-embedded files to output folder' - what was happening is during the build flex was telling me it was 'refreshing' my amfphp folder, which I assume means it was scanning it and/or copying the files over again.  I sometimes work over a slow vpn connection, so it takes forever.   If I need it to copy over some resources, I can either do it manually or check the box I suppose.